# Is a label a Java statement or not?

Tags: java, jls

Is a label a Java statement or not and if a label is a statement where is it defined as a statement in the Java Language Specification?

My question relates to the following reply of Jan Lahoda in the bug report that I've sent to Oracle. I'm unable to discuss it there because I can't get an account in the OpenJDK Jira.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8211052

> In case of e.g.:
>   `A: B: while (true) continue A;` the statement on which the "continue" is applied is not "`while (true) continue A;`", but "`B: while (true) continue A;`", and the spec requires the target for continue is a while/do/for statement, which is not fulfilled here. Hence the compile-time error.

I think a label in Java is not a statement and in Jan's example both the `A` and the `B` labels relate to the same while-loop statement and then no compile time error should be triggered.

**Addition:**

Isn't a **labeled** while/do/for statement in Java a while/do/for statement?

Comment: @Thomas It is a theoretical use case. Java allows to have multiple labels of a loop but there is an inconsistency in handling those multiple labels by `continue` and `brake` statements.

Comment: Just reread the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7): it defines "LabeledStatement" as "label: statement" where "statement" can be a "LabeledStatement" and thus "labelA: labelB: statment" _should_ be allowed (albeit it doesn't make much sense and I might miss something). Just to be complete: a label is _not_ a statement in itself but can be part of one.

Answer (score 5):

Following the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) a `Statement` can be

```
StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
LabeledStatement
IfThenStatement
IfThenElseStatement
WhileStatement
ForStatement
```

with `LabeledStatement` being

```
Identifier : Statement
```

and stated

> The Identifier is declared to be the label of the immediately contained Statement

so in case of a loop like

```
public void method() {
    loop1: loop2: while (true) {
        if (true) {
            break loop1;
        } else {
            continue loop1;
        }
    }
}
```

the `Statement` of the `Label` `loop1` is the entire `loop2 ...` stuff.

And if we look at the definition of `break` it is stated that

> the break target need not be a switch, while, do, or for statement.

whereas for the `continue` it states

> The continue target must be a while, do, or for statement, or a compile-time error occurs.

These definitions are properly in line with the compiler giving a compiler error for the `continue loop1` statement and letting `break loop1` be valid since `loop2: ...` is **not** a *"while, do, or for statement"*.

---

Regarding your actual question: *Is label a Java statement or not?*

The following code is perfectly legal and compiles fine

```
public void method() {
    loop:;
}
```

This follows the expansion of `Statement` -> `LabeledStatement` -> `Identifier` : `Statement` -> loop : `Statement` -> loop : `StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement` -> loop : `EmptyStatement` ->

```
loop : ;
```

No, a label is no statement by itself, an identifier (which is then called "label") plus a column plus an `EmptyStatement` (`;`) however is.

---

*Isn't labeled while/do/for statement in Java a while/do/for statement?*

**No!**

A `LabeledStatement` is exactly that: a `LabeledStatement`. A labeled while is `Statement -> Label -> Identifier : Statement -> Identifier : WhileStatement` which is something fundamentally different than `Statement -> WhileStatement`!

Comment: I repeat my additional question. Isn't **labeled** while/do/for statement in Java a while/do/for statement?

Comment: @RostislavKrasny no, why would it? A labeled statement is a labeled statement, a labeled loop is a labeled loop.

Comment: @RostislavKrasny No, a labeled while/do/for statement is not a while/do/for statement.

Comment: @luk2302 Are you trying to say that labeled loop isn't a loop? A named cat isn't a cat? :-)

Comment: @RostislavKrasny in language specification / grammar terms: yes, a "named cat" is not a "cat", it is a "named".

Comment: @luk2302 then a label is a statement and a "named" is an animal, aren't they? But wait, a label itself isn't a statement but an identifier, right? Where JLS allows a labeled statement to be used with `brake`?

Comment: @RostislavKrasny you need to get clear about what words you use, what exact sequence of letters is the thing you call "label"? In `l: if(...) { ... }` the entire thing is a Statement, and in this case it even is a LabeledStatement with the `if ...` part being a nested Statement, `l` is an Idetifier labeling the `if` statement. Your last question does not make sense because `break` does not "use" a "labeled statement", [the expansion rule is `break Identifier(opt)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15)

Answer (score 3):

The [JLS, Section 14.16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.16), talks about the `continue` statement:

> The continue target must be a `while`, `do`, or `for` statement, or a compile-time error occurs.

Simple enough, but let's look at the grammar for a labeled statement ([Section 14.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7)).

> LabeledStatement:
>
> Identifier : Statement

It can contain another statements in general, which in turn may be a `while`, `do`, or `for` ("wdf") statement, or another labeled statement (Section 14.5) (or other kinds of statements).

But the label by itself is not a statement; it needs the other statement as part of itself.

Next, nested labeled statements *are* allowed, so in general you can do something like:

```
A: B: yourStatementHere;
```

You can nest it further if you want:

```
A: B: C: D: E: F: G: yourStatementHere;
```

However, with

```
A: B: while (true) continue A;
```

The statement that `A:` labels is *another* labeled statement, not a "wdf" statement, even if the `B:` labeled statement itself *contains* a `while` statement.

If you put on your lawyer hat, you can argue that the sentence above about the `continue` statement needing to refer to a "wdf" statement says nothing about the "wdf" statement being nested in a labeled statement, so it should be a compiler error.

That seems very picky to me; perhaps the JLS should have had a clause indicating that the "wdf" statement could be itself nested in a labeled statement.

But until that happens, this appears to be a correct, if unintended, consequence of the wording the JLS provides, quoted above.

**So why is `break` allowed to do this?**

```
A: B: while (true) break A;  // no error
```

There is no corresponding line in Section 14.15 of the JLS, which talks about the `break` statement, that enforces that the target of a `break` statement must be a "wdf" statement.  A `break` statement must still be within a "wdf" statement (or a `switch` statement), but there is no corresponding requirement that its label refer to a specific kind of statement.

Comment: How you've got to a conclusion that labeled while/do/for statement isn't a while/do/for statement? Where JLS defines it so? And why it isn't a problem with `brake`?

Comment: I've added an explanation for `break`.  Also, apparently a "wdf" statement inside of a labeled statement is still just a labeled statement.  There is no provision for a "wdf" statement being inside a labeled statement.  If it needs to refer to me, then it can't refer to my house, even if I'm inside my house.